# Runtime Error(Non Zero Exit Code) in CodeChef Program (JAVA)

Tags: java, runtime-error, bluej

Here's the question - 
https://www.codechef.com/DEC17/problems/CPLAY

And here's my solution -

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Penalty_Shoot_Out
{

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        //System.out.println("T: ");
        int T = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        while(T-->0)
        {
            String s = sc.nextLine();
            int l = s.length();
            s = " " + s;
            int A_score = 0, B_score = 0, A_shots = 0, B_shots = 0, flag = 0, A_shots_left = 5, B_shots_left = 5, shots_left = 0;
            Outer:for(int i=1; i<=20; i++)
            {
                char c = s.charAt(i);
                if(i%2==1)
                {
                    flag = 0;
                    A_shots++;
                    A_shots_left--;
                    if(c=='1')
                        A_score++;
                }
                else
                {
                    flag = 1;
                    B_shots++;
                    B_shots_left--;
                    if(c=='1')
                        B_score++;
                }
                if(i<=10)
                {
                    if(A_score<B_score)
                    {
                        if(B_score-A_score>A_shots_left)
                        {
                            System.out.println("TEAM-B " + i);
                            break Outer;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(A_score-B_score>B_shots_left)
                        {
                           System.out.println("TEAM-A " + i);
                           break Outer;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if(i>10 && i<=20)
                {
                    if(i%2==0)
                    {
                        if(A_score>B_score)
                            System.out.println("TEAM-A " + i);
                        else if(B_score>A_score) 
                            System.out.println("TEAM-B " + i);
                        else
                            System.out.println("TIE");
                        break Outer;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

These are the exceptions -

**Exception**

```
in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)

    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)

    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)

    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)

    at Penalty_Shoot_Out.main(Main.java:8)
```

I'm getting the correct answer on my computer, but when I submit it online, I get the **NZEC Runtime** Error.
I tried Googling for solutions and most people said the error might have to do with the main function returning a wrong number or not returning a number. Some said it may be due to the use of a particular function or due to an exception that i am not handling during I/O. However, I haven't been able to figure it out.

I'd really appreciate it if someone could fix my code.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your solution in a try catch.

```
public static void main(String args[]) 
{
  try {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    //System.out.println("T: ");
    int T = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();
    while(T-->0)
    {
       String s = sc.nextLine();
        int l = s.length();
        s = " " + s;
        int A_score = 0, B_score = 0, A_shots = 0, B_shots = 0, flag = 0,
            A_shots_left = 5, B_shots_left = 5, shots_left = 0;
        Outer:for(int i=1; i<=20; i++)
        {
            char c = s.charAt(i);
            if(i%2==1)
            {
                flag = 0;
                A_shots++;
                A_shots_left--;
                if(c=='1')
                    A_score++;
            }
            else
            {
                flag = 1;
                B_shots++;
                B_shots_left--;
                if(c=='1')
                    B_score++;
            }
            if(i<=10)
            {
                if(A_score<B_score)
                {
                    if(B_score-A_score>A_shots_left)
                    {
                        System.out.println("TEAM-B " + i);
                        break Outer;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if(A_score-B_score>B_shots_left)
                    {
                       System.out.println("TEAM-A " + i);
                       break Outer;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(i>10 && i<=20)
            {
                if(i%2==0)
                {
                    if(A_score>B_score)
                        System.out.println("TEAM-A " + i);
                    else if(B_score>A_score) 
                        System.out.println("TEAM-B " + i);
                    else
                        System.out.println("TIE");
                    break Outer;
                }
            }
        }
    }
  } catch(Exception e) {
    return;
  }
}
```

}

Comment: I'd already tried that. That circumvented the error, but now CodeChef tells me my answer is wrong even though my output is just as they want it.

Comment: When I read your question, I focused on making your program run. I just read the example, they don't give you the number of test cases, so T should not be there. Besides, they will try other test cases to try to see if your code fails, try to come up with some edge cases, find the correct answers and test them against your solution